# Determine whether ActiveRecord.TransactionScope succeeded using the OnTransactionCompleted event

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I'm working with the following code to carry out a delete operation using Castle ActiveRecord v1.0.3 (eugh, legacy!).

```
public void Delete(anObject instance)
{
    try
    {
        using (var scope = new ActiveRecord.TransactionScope(TransactionMode.Inherits, OnDispose.Rollback))
        {
            ...(DB Operations)

            scope.VoteCommit();

            MethodCallBecauseOfSuccess();
        }
    }
    catch (NHibernate.TransactionException ex)
    {
        MethodCallBecauseOfFailure();
    }
}
```

The problem is, because of the TransactionMode.Inherits, consumers of this method are allowed to wrap the call to this method in their own ActiveRecord.TransactionScope.  In cases where they do this, the exception does not occur at the point of scope.VoteCommit() and therefore the MethodCallBecauseOfSuccess() is incorrectly invoked.

This is legacy code I am working with so I cannot re-work the consuming code at this point, I can only alter this method.

So I am now looking at the TransactionScope.OnTransactionCompleted event, so that if the transaction scope disappears up into a calling method, I can still trap when it completes, and call the appropriate method, eg:

```
public void Delete(anObject instance)
{
    try
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionMode.Inherits, OnDispose.Rollback))
        {
            scope.OnTransactionCompleted += (sender, args) => 
                                        {
                                            //if FAIL
                                            MethodCallBecauseOfFailure();
                                            //else SUCCEED
                                            MethodCallBecauseOfSuccess();
                                        };

            ...(DB Operations)

            scope.VoteCommit();
        }
    }
    catch (NHibernate.TransactionException ex)
    {
        ...     
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to determine whether the TransactionScope has failed or succeeded.  The params to the anonymous method are sender = the Parent (I think!) transaction scope, and args = empty.  And of course, I can access scope which is the current TransactionScope.  There are very few properties available to inspect.

**Is there any way to detemine whether it has failed or succeeded?**

Answer (score 0):

does the property HasSessionError help?

```
try
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionMode.Inherits, OnDispose.Rollback))
    {
        scope.OnTransactionCompleted += (sender, args) => 
                                    {
                                        TransactionScope sender2 = (TransactionScope)sender;
                                        if(sender2.HasSessionError)
                                          MethodCallBecauseOfFailure();
                                        else
                                          MethodCallBecauseOfSuccess();
                                    };

        ...(DB Operations)

        scope.VoteCommit();
    }
}
catch (NHibernate.TransactionException ex)
{
    ...     
}
```

Greetings

Juy Juka

Comment: No, unfortunately not; It always appears to be `false`.  I've tried wrapping everything in a SessionScope too, but it still remains false.